# How to get places from google maps by location with node js? And then integrate to dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dialogflow-es

I want to do an application in react-native front-end with Dialogflow and nodejs back-end which when I ask for restaurants from Sydney, for example, to return places.

What i do: 
i try to get places from https://maps.googleapis.com

here is my request:

```
if (result.action === 'find-a-place') {
            console.log("am intrat in if")

            let place_type = responses[0].queryResult.parameters.fields['placesType'].stringValue;
            console.log(" places-type e : " + place_type)
            const city = responses[0].queryResult.parameters.fields['location'].listValue.values[0].structValue.fields['city'].stringValue; // city is a required param
            //res.send(city)
            console.log("city: " + city + " and place type is " + place_type)
            //let date = '';
            getPlaces(place_type, city)
                .then((output) => {
                    res.send(output)
                })
        }
```

and here is the function:

```
function getPlaces(place_type, city) {
    // Create the path for the HTTP request to get the weather
    let path_google = '/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query='+place_type+'+in+'+city+'&key='+process.env.YOUR_API_KEY
    console.log('API Request: ' + host_google + path_google);

    //Make the HTTP request to get the weather
    http.get({ host: host_google, path: path_google }, (res) => {
        let body = ''; // var to store the response chunks
        res.on('data', (d) => { body += d; }); // store each response chunk
        res.on('end', () => {
            // After all the data has been received parse the JSON for desired data
            let response = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log("json ul complet: " + response)
          });

        res.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log(`Error calling the weather API: ${error}`)
            reject();
        });
    });
}
```

END THE ERROR:

```
city: Sydney and place type is: restaurant
API Request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurant+in+Sydney&key=AIzaSyB5pzEDTvHZpJh2puV8X6hu6BQqt7D7NSs
Input is TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://maps.googleapis.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
API Request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurant+in+Sydney&key=AIzaSyB5pzEDTvHZpJh2puV8X6hu6BQqt7D7NSs
Input is TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://maps.googleapis.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'https://maps.googleapis.com'
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome! StackOverflow works best when you have a concrete problem that you have tried to solve, but have run into problems where you need help. Questions should show what you've already tried to solve your problem, and clearly illustrate what problems remain. If you're having specific problems with React Native, or the Maps API, or Dialogflow - we can probably help. If you want to know how to get started - that's a big question. Your question is pretty vague - you may want to edit it to be more specific. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you, I just added what I try to do

Comment: Where are you running your node.js backend?

Comment: localhost, and because I need https for Dialogflow i use ngrok

Comment: Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey